# How to encode data for a 3D CNN network on keras?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently working with data (corresponding of proteins structure files, pdb) that is :

- Coordinates centered around one given point.
- With a limit of a 3D Box 20 * 20 * 20, that i decomposed it in voxel of 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 (meaning i have as dimension 40*40*40), meaning i have as a "grid" 64 000 voxels.
- Each box is independant, and configured in the same way (every time there is a XYZ axis and center identical)
- Each point in a given voxel have one of 20 given value (corresponding to a Label Binarized before)

The idea is to create a 3D CNN network where given a box and what it is inside, the network output will predict of the 20 classes corresponding to the type of the 20*20*20 box. To do that, the input shape for the network should be on 4D, and this is where i have some doubts about how i should encode my  numpy array :

(N, 64000*3, 20) ==> (N, ?,?,?, 20) (case where i put each coordinate)

How can i encode in a way that encapsulate each point by their coordinate?

Comment: To answer  on myself, the encoding is pretty simple in fact : 

(N, 64000, 23) ==> (N, 40, 40, 40, 23)

Comment: I posted an answer yesterday, but deleted it shortly after because it seemed to obvious :). Anyways, I undeleted it now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution3d/) of keras API on Conv3D layers regarding the input shape (which is a required keyword for the layer)

> 5+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) if data_format='channels_first' or 5+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) if data_format='channels_last'.

This means that in each sample you need to specify the 3 input dimensions of the cube, which in your case will be equal to the shape `(40,40,40)` (which elements will be scaled by the voxel size) and there will be 20 input channels.

This means that the input shape will equal:
(N, 64000*3, 20) ==> (N, 40, 40, 40, 20)

The output shape of the Conv3D layer will be determined by the convolving filters. The filter will have 5 dimensions: 3 convolution dimensions which will align with the kernel shape, and the input and output dimension. But keras will handle these dimensions for you so no need to specify it. The first argument of the Conv3D layer (filters) is the number of output dimensions. You also need to specify the kernel shape or size, which will conventionally be a fraction of the input dimensions (for example `(4,4,4)`).

For your task the network output will be a softmax layer and typically include some intermediary layers like maxpool or ReLU.

Comment: Yes that's exactly how it worked out after i thought about. I would even add, that in the end, i didn't kept the coordinate for two mains reasons, first the weight difference between the 20 vector values (which correspond to labels binarized in fact) and the coordinates, and secondly the fact that since it's a conv3D with voxel, coordinates will be implicitly learnt (in my case because each coordinates correspond to a center of those voxels where the coordinate were checked being in the voxel or not). Thanks a lot for your answer, it confirm that it works the way i thought